# Detect when audio card is powered (using alsa)

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

How can I detect in a script if my audio card is being powered?

Motivation: I have a Linux mini computer (`Odroid U3`), used as a music player. And I want to power on a connected amplifier only when there is some a sound being played.
For this I need to detect somehow if audio is being powered on and off.

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/393448/detecting-audio-playing-in-a-bash-script) suggests that it's possible to read the `ALSA` state from some files in `/proc`, which are actually not files, so `inotify` doesn't work, and polling is not an option since it wastes power, and I need immediate detection of audio power on.

Is there some system event or alsa event that I can wait on in a script, that would tell me about changes in audio hardware being powered on/off?
Then I'd write a script with a never-ending loop, waiting for the event, powering my amplifier, and repeat waiting.

Comment: I'm looking for solution to the same problem. And after some research I find that you can use inotify on /dev/snd/* which might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel has auditing support enabled (which is unlikely for an embedded distribution), you can get notified when somebody accesses the sound device files.

Otherwise, this must be done in userspace.
The ALSA library has support for virtual [devices that can call a hook function](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html#pcm_plugins_hooks) in a shared library.
This is rather undocumented; the only example is the `_snd_pcm_hook_ctl_elems_install()` function, which changes and restores some mixer controls while the PCM device is being used.